# No audio from mpd via wlan0 after disconnecting eth0

Tags: alsa

Set-up:

- Raspbian Jessie Lite 4.9
- Model B+
- Edimax ew-7811un

I'm running an internet radio stream to the built-in audio interface using mpd/mpc. And audio plays just fine as long as the ethernet interface is connected. That ethernet interface is used for SSH via my MacBook's internet sharing - so eth0 has internet connection.

I also have wlan0 interface running (via Edimax ew-7811un) and that appears to work ok (I can ping and run apt-get update) by itself.

However, as soon as I disconnect the ethernet internet connection (either by unplugging the cable or disabling internet on my Mac), the mpd audio goes silent.

Trying...

```
mpc stop
mpc play
```

...just shows that mpd thinks it's playing fine (time elapses correctly/no error message about not being able to find the stream).

Any ideas where to look? Does mpd/ALSA need to be told where to get audio?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, writing out the question is enough of a push to figure out the answer myself...

For some reason in /etc/mpd.conf

```
bind_to_address "localhost"
```

...was set. I changed it to:

```
bind_to_address "any"
```

...and now mpd plays correctly via wlan0. Lovely.